# TinyMCE 5: Add custom attribute to toolbar button

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-plugins

Is there a way to add a custom attribute to a toolbar button / custom toolbar button?

I'm doing some tests and I need to get those buttons by custom attributes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way at the moment, no, although it is something we've considered to make our tests easier to write.

For the moment we use the `aria-label` to find buttons (e.g. querySelector for `button[aria-label="Remove link"]`) although that does mean our tests can only run in one language.

Comment: It is very annoying not to be able to identify the IU buttons other than with the aria-label, which is actually language dependent.

I currently have a way around it, which is to identify my svg icons and then go back to the buttons to assign them an identifier, but what complications...

If we could create buttons with custom attributes it would be great

Anyway, many thanks for the great tinyMce 5 API